# Contact Form - Missing submissions

Tags: craft3, plugin-contactform

Good Evening and Merry Christmas.

We are having an issue with some contact form submissions are not submitting emails and the database entry, however they continue through to the redirect page.

The affected submissions seem to be ipad related so far.

I have updated cms and all plugins to latest versions.
submissions are sent via SMTP using Sendgrid.

Can you suggest a way to diagnose the issue?

Comment: Do you have a honey pot enabled?

Answer (score 1):

I would first check any form submission/validation code you might have - it sounds like the redirect is firing before the form actually submits. It may be allowing blanks through, or you could be running into an order of operations issue.